# How to know the time at which kernel starts executing after interruption?

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, kernel, interrupt

Linux already contains all the interrupt handling for network data. don't have to do anything regarding this. Data arrives, Linux will process it (in the kernel) and pass it to the process waiting for the data. do not write interrupt handlers for network devices. You don't have to write an interrupt handler, because all the interrupt handlers needed are already provided by Linux. Just have your program read from the opened socket.

I want to know the time at which the kernel starts executing after the interruption. could some one help me how to know the time at which the kernel starts executing ??

how to copy the time when the interrupt occurs and send it back as a response to the client.

Comment: Please, specify what is the "begging event" and the "target event" - for which you want to know latency (difference between which events do you want).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Kernel interrupt debugging for rt linux or qnx?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22708390/kernel-interrupt-debugging-for-rt-linux-or-qnx)

Comment: I forgot to mention : it is an embedded pc target with real time linux or qnx real time operating system.

Answer (score 1):

This time will change according to what the machine is currently doing, if it is in a critical section where the interruptions are masked it will wait. Hopefully these critical sections are short.
You can use a logic analyser to look at that (I did it a long long time ago on a Windows NT machine - pentium 100 MHz, and the usual interrupt latency was a few micro seconds, while with an IDE drive busy at the same time it was often 100 ms). I bet that with a recent machine and linux standard kernel it should always be a few microseconds, less than 30, but that's just a guess. Real time linux kernel will have a consistent response time.

Comment: I forgot to mention : it is an embedded pc target with real time linux or qnx real time operating system. then how can I find a timestamp when the interrupt occurs in kernel ??

Comment: You can use Linux Tracing Toolkit (LTTNG) to get timestamp of interrupt. In QNX you can use instrumented kernel (http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.3.0SP3/neutrino/sys_arch/trace.html) - there are interrupt events.

Comment: The preemption level the kernel is compiled with, along with what else is running on the system will be your major factors.  I'm taking it when you say real-time kernel, you're implying the RT_PREEMPT patch, but even that has several options on how it can be compiled (PREEMPT_FULL, PREEMPT_RTB, PREEMPT__LL), etc.  Your best bet is to use an analyzer as Nocolas suggested.